# Problem with 'this' in a nested function and undefined value

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, dropzone

I have problem with getting into my file in Dropzone (ngx-dropzone-wrapper). I'm displaying in console.log my variable "file" and I'm getting undefined. How to get access into this file?

I tried lamba expression and in my tslint error has disappeared with "this.file", but still I have undefined this.file in my importCR function.

```
public config: DropzoneConfigInterface;
file: File;

this.config = {
//some code here and...
  accept: this.acceptFiles.bind(this)  //bind here is not working I guess..
};

public acceptFiles(file, done) {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener('loadEnd', (e: any) => {
   this.file = e.target.result;
  });
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

public importCR() {
  console.log(this.file); //returns 'undefined'
}
```

Now I get udefined in "importCR" function and should be some data.

Comment: `this` in an event is not gonna refer to the context in which the event was declared. It will either refer to window or the event target. You can create a variable pointing to `this` in the acceptFiles function and reference that variable in the event handler.

Comment: Oh also, if you want to use `.bind` to fix it, you can use it for the event handler. Pass `((e: any) => {
   this.file = e.target.result;
  }).bind(this)` as the handler

Comment: @ChrisRollins There is still problem.

     `accept: function (file, done) {
            {
              const self = this;
              const reader = new FileReader();

              reader.addEventListener('loadEnd', (e: any) => {
                self.file = e.target.result;
              });
              reader.readAsText(file);
            }
          }.bind(this)`


It is not working.
I get undefined again.

Comment: Are you sure the event is firing?

Comment: Right, event wasn't firing. It was typo in eventListener "loadEnd" should be "loadend". Now everything is working, thank You a lot!